# Getting an error while using range(len(list)) v/s enumerate(list)

Tags: python, python-3.x

so I had written a code and successfully executed it using enumerate(list). Due to my experimental nature, I tried to replace enumerate(list) with range(len(list)). But to my surprise, I received an error. I would really love to know the reason behind the same.

```
for pos, val in enumerate(list):
        return something
---------------------------------
Ran successfully
---------------------------------
            v/s

for pos, val in range(len(list)):
        return something
-----------ERROR---------------
for pos, val in range(len(q)):
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
-------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to unpack a single-depth iterable with `pos, val`. Take a look at the below example and note the difference in the output data.

```py
li = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

print(*range(len(li)))
print(*enumerate(li))
```

Output

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
(0, 1) (1, 2) (2, 3) (3, 4) (4, 5) (5, 6) (6, 7) (7, 8) (8, 9) (9, 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually the `enumerate()` method adds a counter to an iterable and returns it in a form of enumerating object.

But range() generates a series of numbers within a given range.

That's why you are getting the error while running the above code.

You can try this -

```
for val in range(len(list)):
    #your code
```

Also please avoid using list name as `list`. It is a built-in function in python and will create confusion.